# Did Hawkgirl in the DCAU ever have a musical theme?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, theme-music

Besides Hawkgirl, all the other founding members of the Justice League in the DCAU had a musical theme.  Plenty of other DCAU characters had them too (Aquaman, Green Arrow, Supergirl, Batgirl, almost every Batman villain).

There was never any theme I connected with Hawkgirl though.  This might just be because I never managed to separate it out and associate it with her.  I didn't really link the Martian Manhunter or Wonder Woman themes to their characters until it was pointed out to me.

I've tried looking on You Tube and there are plenty of compilations of DCAU music, but none of them seem to have a Hawkgirl theme.

Answer (score 2):

### It would appear she does not.

Here is a complication of all the themes in the DCAU for heroes. She isn't included.

Perhaps the closest thing I found was from the Starcrossed Soundtrack, a song titled Farewell Hawkgirl.

Answer (score -2):

No. Only Superman and Batman have individual themes due to having had their own shows, which is a shame. Back in the 80's, each if the Thundercats had his or her musical ID, even Snarf (Wilykit & Wilykat shared).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems to contradict the question and existing answer, which both claim that _most_ of the heroes had themes.  If you're going to disagree with a premise of the question you should provide evidence, and you should make sure you have something new that isn't covered in existing answers.  Please read [answer].